# Don't know how to build task 'symlink_directories'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano, capistrano3, rvm1-capistrano3

After upgrading a rails project, I'm trying to deploy with capistrano and suddenly getting this error:

```
Tasks: TOP => deploy:restart
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Don't know how to build task 'symlink_directories' (see --tasks)
```

My `Capfile`:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require "rvm1/capistrano3"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
require "capistrano/rails"
require "capistrano/passenger"

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Gemfile.lock capistrano related gems:

```
    capistrano (3.7.1)
      capistrano-harrow
    capistrano-bundler (1.2.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
    capistrano-harrow (0.5.3)
    capistrano-passenger (0.2.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
    capistrano-rails (1.2.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    rvm1-capistrano3 (1.4.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      capistrano (>= 3.5.0)
  capistrano (~> 3.7)
  capistrano-bundler (~> 1.2)
  capistrano-passenger
  capistrano-rails (~> 1.2)
  rvm1-capistrano3
```

Comment: What was the previous version of Capistrano that you were using? I would simply set the same version on the Gemfile

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to revert if there's no better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `cap -T | grep symlink` and saw there's a task with a similar name, so I just band-aided the problem by calling it from the `deploy` namespace.

```
cap deploy:symlink:linked_dirs     # Symlink linked directories
```